# How to tell PEX to use the mock object when the concrete object is a dependency, and then auto-generate test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, pex

I am writing client-side components in a provided framework, and need to be able to unit test my components. The components are written using MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern, I want to use PEX to automatically generate unit tests for my presenters.

The following is the code of a presenter.

```
public partial class CompetitorPresenter : PresenterBase
{

    private readonly ICompetitorView _view; 

    public IGlobalDataAccess GlobalDataAccess;

    public IGlobalUI Globals;

    public SystemClient Client;

    public bool DeleteRecord()
   {
           if (_view.CompetitorName != "Daniel")
                return false;
           if (Client.SystemName != "Ruby")
                return false;
           return true;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the object `SystemClient` is provided by the framework, and I cannot use a factory class to create an instance of `SystemClient`. Therefore when I run PEX to automatically generate unit tests, I have to tell PEX to ignore `SystemClient`, the result of this is that the method `DeleteRecord` is not fully covered as the line `Client.SystemName != "Ruby"` is not tested.

Since I have the mock object `MSystemClient` (created using moles), I am wondering if somewhere in the configuration I could tell PEX to use `MSystemClient`, and let PEX to automatically generate test cases to fully cover this method.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If you cannot control where the instance of `CompetitorPresenter.Client` is created, you can define a mole for all instances:

```
MSystemClient.AllInstances.SystemNameGet = () => "SomeName";
```

Your unit test has to be run in a "hosted environment":

```
[HostType("Moles")]
public void TestMethod()
{
  MSystemClient.AllInstances.SystemNameGet = () => "SomeName";

  // Test code...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. The solution I am after is to let PEX automatically generate test cases without manually writing the moles code. I was hoping for a PEX configuration option.